# Create a favicon for a link that is JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, anchor, bookmarklet, favicon

I have a link on my site that is strictly JavaScript, that the users can optionally drag to their browser's link bar. Because there is no associated site with a Favicon, the link always gets a blank icon. Is there anyway to associate a Favicon with it at the time the user drags it? I am primarily interested in a Firefox solution, but IE would be nice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do this. In Firefox for example all my bookmarklets are just blank pages.

The alternative would be to point to an HTML file (on a server with a favicon). that only contains the script

Comment: The alternative is not possible, since the javascript needs to access the current page the user is on, not a page on my site.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a way to do this in Firefox using the [Favicon Picker 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3176) addon.  I have a couple of different bookmarklets that I have custom icons on my shortcut bar and bookmarks.